A mini sandwich - Dekadoku
A new puzzle, very interesting to solve. The rules are as follows:



Place all the two-digit combinations (numbers from 00 to 99).




In each row or column, no number can have the same tens digit.




In each row or column, no number can have the same units digit.
Color is decorative. Good luck...





Is this actually a [tag:magic-square], or would [tag:grid-deduction] be more accurate?

Penpa+ link

Hopefully someone other than @Beastly Gerbil solves it this time :)

Here's the solution (red = already used numbers):

 

